# How Does PHP Send Mail Using mail() Without sendmail?

Tags: php, email, sendmail

Okay, so I have a simple script that sends an e-mail via PHP's mail function like so:

```
<?php mail('foo@example.org', 'Subject', 'This is a message', array('From' => 'bar@example.org', 'To' => 'foo@example.org', 'Subject' => 'This is a message')); ?>
```

It works perfectly when run on a Synology DS212j (a Linux-based NAS using BusyBox for most common shell commands), however as far as I can tell there is no instance of `sendmail` anywhere that I can find, and the BusyBox `sendmail` isn't enabled. In fact, if I use `ini_get("sendmail_path")` then a value of `" -t -i"` is returned.

There's an environment variable of `MAIL=/var/mail/root` but this doesn't to do anything either (there is no `/var/mail`).

So I'm at a complete loss as to how PHP is actually sending its e-mail, so I'm hoping someone might know. I'm having trouble going through `sendmail` for PHP on another platform (on the same network *sigh*) so if I can use the same mechanism as my NAS then it could make things easier.

Comment: sendmail's not the only mailer. postfix/exim will create a sendmail symlink to their own binaries for compatibility with apps which have a hardcoded "all email goes through sendmail" assumption.

Answer (score 4):

If you have **qmail** or **postfix** on your system and they are configured with sendmail wrappers, then PHP can be configured to work with these. Otherwise sendmail binaries must be on the system for php to send email using mail() function.

reference : http://php.net/manual/en/mail.requirements.php

Comment: That seems reasonable, but in that case why wouldn't `sendmail_path` be pointing to such a binary? Is there some other way I can find out what my PHP installation is actually using? I'll take a look at to see if I can locate qmail or postfix, I doubt my NAS will have more than one of these installed, but I'm still at a loss as to how PHP is actually configured to use them given what I see in the configuration options and `phpinfo()` results.